# Python difflib: difflib's htmldiff merges multiple lines into one

Tags: python, diff

I have to compare 2 python strings, each of which is a multiline string (these are read from a file).

My code is this

```
list1 = [string1]
list2 = [string2]
differ = difflib.HtmlDiff()
htmlOut = differ.make_file(list1, list2)
```

When I copy htmlOut to an HTML file and open it in Chrome, multiline strings became a single line string.

I've also tried directly printing htmlOut to a file and then open that file. Even this approach doesn't work. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace python `\n` with `<br>` for HTML